# Can't reach Blade engine to include section

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and trying to play with Blade.

So, in  **/app/views/layouts/test.blade.php** I have

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST LAYOUT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>{{ date('d/m') }}</p>
        <p>
            @yield('content')
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

in **/app/views/testView.blade.php** is

```
@secton('content')
    <p>{{ 'Hello World from section...' }}</p>
@stop

{{'Hi every one'}}

<p>It doesn't work :(</p>
```

And my **controller** is as follows:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'layouts.test';

    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('testView');
    }

}
```

But the final output looks like this:

```
Hi every one

<p>It doesn't work :(</p>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST LAYOUT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>02/12</p>
        <p>
                    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried another way (without protected $layout in controller but with @extends in testView.blade.php) but the result is the same. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @secton('content') => @section('content')?

Comment: I looked few times before posted to StackOverflow but really didn't saw it.

Comment: Happens to the best of us (:

Answer (score 0):

You didnt call the test.blade.php properly.
Your 
/app/views/testView.blade.php should look like this

```
@extends('layouts/test)
@secton('content')
    <p>{{ 'Hello World from section...' }}</p>
@stop

{{'Hi every one'}}

<p>It now works :)</p>
```

It should work now

Comment: yeah just saw that after i posted mine too.....it probably got solved wgile i was typing mine.....but no problem about that though